# Slow performance using .head() with pandas in loop

Tags: python, pandas, performance, dictionary, dataframe

I was amazed to discover how much of a performance slowdown I incurred when using a for loop and the `.head()` method in pandas. I am looking for any advice to my problem, which I illustrate below.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#create dictionary of 10000 dataframes
numdfs = 10000

alldf = {i:pd.DataFrame({'a':np.random.randn(250),'b':np.random.randn(250),'c':np.random.randn(250),'d':np.random.randn(250)}) for i in range(numdfs)}

count = 250
runningsum = 0
for i in range(numdfs):
    df = alldf[i].head(count)
    df['is negative'] = (df['b'] < 0).cummax().astype(int)
    runningsum += df['is negative'].max()
```

The above code takes about 15 minutes to execute on my machine, while removing the `.head(count)` from the first line after the for loop makes it execute in under a minute!

can someone share some perspective on why this is, and how i can enhance performance? the .head() is used because in the real example, i want to evaluate the condition up to potentially a different number of samples in the dataframes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(df['b'] < 0).cummax().astype(int).max()` simply checks if any value
   is less than 0. You can use `(df['b'] < 0).any()` instead. There's
   also no need for `int` conversion as Boolean values are considered
   `1` / `0` for `True` / `False` respectively.

As a side note, `loc` / `iloc` tend to be more efficient than other forms of slicing, but this isn't the main driver of poor performance, despite your tests.

You can use a generator expression with `sum` for the equivalent algorithm:

```
sum((v.loc[:250, 'b'] < 0).any() for v in alldf.values())
```

Here's some performance benchmarking:

```
np.random.seed(0)  # use this to reproduce results
numdfs = 10**2     # create 100 dataframes

alldf = {i: pd.DataFrame({col: np.random.randn(250) for col in 'abcd'}) \
         for i in range(numdfs)}

def jpp(alldf):
    return sum((v.loc[:250, 'b'] < 0).any() for v in alldf.values())

def original(alldf):
    count=250
    runningsum = 0
    for i in range(len(alldf)):
        df = alldf[i].head(count)
        df['is negative'] = (df['b'] < 0).cummax().astype(int)
        runningsum += df['is negative'].max()
    return runningsum

assert jpp(alldf) == original(alldf)

%timeit jpp(alldf)       # 46.6 ms
%timeit original(alldf)  # 6.46 s
```

The algorithm is still pretty slow as you are needlessly checking *every* single value in `'b'` when it's possible to short-circuit if a value less than zero is found. A loopy way is possible with `numba` which improves on the original algorithm by a factor of ~12,000x.

```
from numba import njit

@njit
def any_below_zero(arr, k):
    for i in range(k):
        if arr[i] < 0:
            return 1
    return 0

def jpp_nb(alldf):
    return sum(any_below_zero(v['b'].values, 250) for v in alldf.values())

%timeit jpp_nb(alldf)    # 525 µs
```

For 10,000 dataframes, as in your tests, this works in less than a second:

```
numdfs = 10**5     # create 10000 dataframes
alldf = {i: pd.DataFrame({col: np.random.randn(250) for col in 'abcd'}) \
         for i in range(numdfs)}

%timeit jpp_nb(alldf)    # 746 ms
```

Comment: the main reason why the .cummax().astype(int) is used is because i want to record at which observation the condition is satisfied, and fill the remaining ones to indicate it having taken place

Comment: @laszlopanaflex, But that's not what your code is doing... `df['is negative'].max()` in your code will always be 0 or 1. If there's a separate problem with your algorithm, I suggest fixing that first (and possibly ask a separate question if you get stuck). That said, `numba` may still help.

Comment: df['is negative'] = (df['b'] < 0).cummax().astype(int) - this line creates the column i was referring to

Comment: @laszlopanaflex, Yes, but then you take the maximum in the next line, i.e. `runningsum += df['is negative'].max()`... which will be `0` or `1`.

Comment: you are right - even revisiting my actual code (not the toy example here), the recording/creation of that column is not necessary in this loop (it gets overwritten every time anyway) - using the sum(boolean).any() approach makes a huge difference - im amazed how much!